# Cross validation on the whole dataset and vectorisation of data

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, cross-validation, text-classification

I have a methodological doubt concerning cross validation (CV). I have found some academic papers that report results applying CV over a whole dataset. So, let's say I want to do that. My doubt comes when we have to work with text and apply first some transformations on the data, like vectorisation. In that case, should we apply vectorisation on the whole dataset, without splitting into train/test? The best solution I have found for that is to use a pipeline like the following one, which I use to vectorise a Part of Speech representation of texts:

```
pipe = make_pipeline(ColumnSelector(column='pos'), 
                  TfidfVectorizer(binary=True, ngram_range=(1,3), max_features=5000),
                  SVC(kernel='linear', random_state=seed))enter code here
```

Then I use this pipeline to run CV over the whole dataset:

```
cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(pipe, X, y, cv=skf, scoring=scoring)
```

I would like to make sure that this method is correct and sound.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that your pipeline approach will handle this situation for you. In other words: TfidfVectorizer will go through the CV process, and in each combination of training folds it will call .fit_transform; then for that fold's corresponding heldout test score it will call .transform only. That emulates a real-world scenario where you'd be applying the results of a pre-trained process to new unseen data (emulated by 'test' data), so you'd have to transform based on a prior fit Vocab (Vectorizer).

I'm basing my understanding of the sklearn specific mechanics off of a response I saw here:

[Are the k-fold cross-validation scores from scikit-learn's `cross_val_score` and `GridsearchCV` biased if we include transformers in the pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57651455/are-the-k-fold-cross-validation-scores-from-scikit-learns-cross-val-score-and)

The responder subclasses a StandardScaler class in a Pipeline and shows that on the heldout folds it is only calling .transform as it runs through a cv class. My current understanding is that any Class fed into cross_val_score that can accept pipe inputs with classes defining .fit_transform and .transform options will handles this.